# Как задать величину отступа по вертикали между контейнерами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlayout, spacing

В главном контейнере `main_box` я создаю четыре пустых контейнера:

- Один контейнер `big_box` высотой 200px
- Три контейнера `little_box`(в цикле) высотой 50px

Я хочу выставить значения отступов по вертикали между этими контейнерами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**H** - это расстояние между `big_box` и самым верхним `little_box`. Оно должно быть постоянно и равно 40px.

**L** - это расстояние между контейнерами `little_box`. Оно должно быть постоянно и равно 20px.

**Очень важно! -> При этом мне нужно оставить `big_box` вверху контейнера `main_box`.**

Пожалуйста, помогите расположить виджеты в контейнере

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #1F252F;')
        container.setFixedHeight(200)
        big_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
        main_box.addWidget(container, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet('background-color: #1F252F;')
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            little_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            main_box.addWidget(container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Посмотрите метод `setMargin`.

Comment: @And, мне кажется он предназначен только для виджетов `QLabel`. Может быть, я что-то не понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #FF252F;')
        container.setFixedHeight(200)
        big_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
        main_box.addWidget(container, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        main_box.addSpacing(40)                                               # +++

        start = 0                                                             # +++
        end = 3                                                               # +++
        for i in range(start, end):           # (0, 3):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet('background-color: #1F25FF;')
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            little_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            main_box.addWidget(container)

            if i != end-1:                                                     # +++
                main_box.addSpacing(20)                                        # +++
        main_box.addStretch(1)                                                 # +++  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]